# Drupal 8: configuration menu doesn't work

Tags: drupal-8

Drupal 8: configuration menu doesn't  work. When I login and click on Configuration, I've got as below:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Is it possible that this is hosting problem?
 I've installed Drupal locally and have no this problem..

How to fix it and see configuration?

I've tried "one click installation" and install Drupal under another domain but this installation doesn't provide option for Modules as "list", "update", "uninstall" and allow only to download modules...

I was told that this on click installation  out of date and I should install from Drupal.org but that installation also failed(see error above regarding configuration)
thanks.

Comment: All the other menus items work fine except for Configuration? I also recommend not using "one click installation" if your webhost supports self installation.

Comment: Yes, other menu items work as expected except that if I install a new module that I created- it show the same error about website error. And it is my installation Drupal 8.2.6 from Drupal org.

Comment: As I wrote installation from on click doesn't  provide  "list", "update", "uninstall" options and also created error when I install a new module...
There is no problem when I use Drupal locally.  Should I install another version/any suggestion?

Comment: Are you able to connect with http://yoursite.com/admin/config or http://yoursite.com/admin/config/system/site-information

Comment: Not, when I click on Configuration - I got empty space  with one line

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: I asked about going there directly to those two addresses. I did not ask about clicking on Configuration.

Comment: create settings.local.php in your sites/default folder by copying default.settings.php with this line - 

$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';

You should be able to view the detailed error. If you can post it to your question, it would help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

I've updated to the new version and I also changed path during installation. It was localhost and I changed it on the path to the server of my host.
After mention above action I could see output.